# UITextField within UITableViewCell -- programmatically make it firstResponder when it comes on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a UITextField inside of each cell.  A model object that stores the index of the cell that is currently being edited.  If the cell scrolls off-screen, my app takes away first-responder status.  (Failing to do so may cause problems).  Now, suppose a cell (possibly the same one, or possibly a different one) corresponding to that index is about to scroll back onto the screen.  I want to make that cell's textField the firstResponder.  My delegate does receive a call

```
tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:
```

corresponding to the new cell.  However, calling becomeFirstResponder: at that point does not help as the cell won't accept firstResponder status until it has been displayed.

Short of using a timer, any ideas for how to call becomeFirstResponder: at a point when the cell is in fact able to become the first responder?

EDIT: cellForRowAtIndexPath: is always called before willDisplayCell:.  So no help there.

Comment: any time when cell appeares -cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method is called,so,did u try to set uitextfield as first responder there?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but the first thing I'd try is in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // standard stuff to build cell and setup it's state

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.myModel.indexPathOfTextFieldBeingEdited]) {
        // you probably have a handle to the text field from the setup above
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:SOME_TAG];
        [textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Tried. No good.  The problem is again that the cell has not been displayed.

Comment: did you use performSelector?  It certainly has been displayed after cellForRowAtIndexPath has returned and the main loop has returned.

Comment: That's effectively a timer.  A delay like that will generally work.  But it's not ideal programming style and could be broken by an Apple update.

Comment: Delay is 0.0, which just says queue this message to run as soon as possible after the current run loop returns.  Not sure I see your point about programming style, or why this - as opposed to any other part of the sdk behavior - would be more subject to change by apple.  ...But of course I accept your non-acceptance :).

Comment: Right, and what if things change so that the next iteration of the run loop is no longer good enough?

Comment: You might be right.  I just don't see why that's more probable than any other sdk change.  And it isn't catastrophic: if it breaks later, fix it on the next release.  I think you're more likely to run afoul of Apple because this thing we're trying to accomplish probably violates Apple HIG.  Anyway, as I said, I realize that on SO, you're the boss of what's a correct answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show cell on the screen to make it as first responder. Do at first:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
```

and then call first responder on it's label/textField.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in MonoTouch - it's important that you do not animate the ScrollToRow() - i.e. "animated:NO" as shown in the answer by edzio27 (thanks edzio27 :) ).

```
var newCell = (UIOrderLineCell)tableView.CellAt(newIndexPath);
if (newCell == null)
{
    tableView.ScrollToRow(newIndexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, false);
    newCell = (UIOrderLineCell)tableView.CellAt(newIndexPath);
}
```